# how to make long thead text two linear

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap 4 table, Texts in thead are so long. Right now it's coming in four lines
so I need to make those two liner. I have tried `"white-space: pre"` but because of this it's been one linear, I want to make it two liner how to solve this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        .item-table th{
            white-space: pre;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <table class="table table-bordered item-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.No.</th>
            <th>Items</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of smith deen</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Paskal</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Peter</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of lynda</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of James</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Anne</th>
    
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Rudina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Addrina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Anjelina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Ryan</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of ramon</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of mannel</th>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Books</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Bed</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Chair</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    
    </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Maybe give the `th` a min-width in `em` or something.

Comment: max-width more likely; I've even gone so far as to include a ton of "&shy;" and <br>-tags with classes attached to them so I can toggle them ON/OFF via MediaQueries.

Comment: Thanks CBroe it's working for me

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving the repeated information into its own row with a `colspan`:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered item-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Sr.No.</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Items</th>
            <th colspan="12">Item rating according to choice of...</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>smith deen</th>
            <th>Paskal</th>
            <th>Peter</th>
            <th>lynda</th>
            <th>James</th>
            <th>Anne</th>
            <th>Rudina</th>
            <th>Addrina</th>
            <th>Anjelina</th>
            <th>Ryan</th>
            <th>ramon</th>
            <th>mannel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Books</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Bed</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Chair</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: your table structure is looks nice but am constrained , can not do these changes in table.

Answer (score 0):

another not perfect, but working solution to split the text without interfereing the tables auto-sizing (example-code):

css:

```
    th {
        white-space: nowrap, // or pre
    }
```

javascript:

```js
    function wrapString (str) {
        l = Math.floor (str.length / 2);
        s = str.substr (0, l);
        i = s.lastIndexOf (" ");
        return str.substr(0, i)+"<br>"+str.substr(i+1)
    }
    
    $("th").map (function () {
      $(this).html (wrapString($(this).text()));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**#Use `min-width:200px;` To Split Text To Next Line**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.item-table th {
    min-width: 200px;
    /* min-width:13em; */
}
</style>

<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered item-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.No.</th>
            <th>Items</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of smith deen</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Paskal</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Peter</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of lynda</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of James</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Anne</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Rudina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Addrina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Anjelina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Ryan</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of ramon</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of mannel</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Books</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Bed</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Chair</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**#Use `<br>` Tags To Move Text To Next Line (With `white-space:pre;`)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>table.item-table th {white-space:pre;}</style>  </head>

        <body>
            <table class="table table-bordered item-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Sr.No.</th>
                    <th>Items</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of smith deen</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of Paskal</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of Peter</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of lynda</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of James</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of Anne</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of Rudina</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of Addrina</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of Anjelina</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of Ryan</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of ramon</th>
                    <th>Item rating according to<br>choise of mannel</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Table</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Books</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Bed</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Chair</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>

</html>
```

**#OR JS Code By @Makkapitew (For Inserting `<br>` Tags Automatically)**

```js
function wrapString (str) { l = Math.floor (str.length / 2); s = str.substr (0, l); i = s.lastIndexOf (" "); return str.substr(0, i)+"<br>"+str.substr(i+1) } $("th").map (function () { $(this).html (wrapString($(this).text())); });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.item-table th {
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>

<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered item-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.No.</th>
            <th>Items</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of smith deen</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Paskal</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Peter</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of lynda</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of James</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Anne</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Rudina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Addrina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Anjelina</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of Ryan</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of ramon</th>
            <th>Item rating according to choise of mannel</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Books</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Bed</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Chair</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use ellipsis css property

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: I think the text was supposed to be still readable in full. Your solution may be pratical - as long as you place the entire table header text into a title attribute .. and are sure you're not on a touch device .. which seems highly unlikely nowadays. ;-)